# IFrame Problems: Footer is on top of iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, footer

I know this might be staring at me right in the face, but I can't quite pin-point what might be causing my problem.  I have a footer and an iframe that aren't playing nice together.  My footer is sitting on top of my iframe. I need my footer to sit at the bottom of my page, just like all of my other pages, and stay there, regardless if a user scrolls up and down.  Just need it to stay at the bottom.  I'm not quite sure if its a positioning issue, a div issue, if it's the footer's problem, or the iframe's problem.  I'm guessing it's the footer's problem, but the footer is placed where I need it on all of my other pages.  That's what's confusing me.  Still new to web page design, so I'm still wrapping my head around positioning properties and what not.  Here is what I have:

CSS:

```
/*BODY*/
html, body {
    background:White;
    font-family:Segoe UI;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

#body {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:460px;
}

.footer1 {
    background-color:#494949;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:360px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100px;
    left: 0;
}

.footer2 {
    background-color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    /*margin-top:0px;*/
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pagina De Informacion General</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, css3, sliding, box, menu, cube, navigation, portfolio, thumbnails"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CaseTypes/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <script src="/NewWebTest/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!--HEADER-->
            <div id="header">
            </div>

            <!--PAGE TITLE-->
            <div id="pageTitle">
                Pagina De Informacion General
            </div>

            <!--NAVIGATION MENU-->
            <div id="navigation">
            </div>

            <br/>

        <div id="body" style="height:100%">
        <div style="height: 532px">
            <div id="openingImage">
                <img src="../images/Blended Courthouse JPG Less Opacity.jpg" alt="Courthouse" height="274" width="1271"/>           
            </div>

            <!--DIV LEFT: ANNOUNCEMENTS-->
            <div id="annouceDiv">

                <div class="sectionHeader">
                    &nbsp&nbsp Ubicación Central
                </div>
                <br/>

                <div class="announceSection" style="text-align:center">
                    Pima County Consolidated Justice Court<br/>
                    240 N. Stone Avenue, segundo piso<br/>
                    Tucson, AZ 85701<br/>
                    (520) 724-3171 <br/><br/>   

                    Para obtener información sobre estacionamiento, visite el sitio web de la Ciudad de Tucson:<br/>
                    <a href="https://www.tucsonaz.gov/park-tucson/where-can-i-park-downtown" target="_blank">City of Tucson Downtown Parking</a>                
                </div>

                <!--SECTION DIVIDER IMAGE-->
                <div class="breakImageDiv">
                    <img src="../images/EchoPet_Line_Break_PNG.png" class="breakImagePic" alt="Divider"/>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="annouceDiv">

                <div class="sectionHeader">
                    &nbsp&nbsp Horario y Cierre por Dias Festivos
                </div>
                <br/>

                <div class="announceSection" style="text-align:center">
                    Lunes a Viernes, 8:00 a.m. to 5:00 p.m., excepto días festivos<br/>
                    <table style="margin:auto; width:100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Año Nuevo</td>
                            <td>Día del Obrero</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Día de Martin Luther King</td>
                            <td>Día del Armisticio</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Día de los Presidentes</td>
                            <td>Día de Acción de Gracías</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Día de los Caídos</td>
                            <td>Día despues de Acción de Gracías</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Día de la Independencia</td>
                            <td>Navidad</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>                
                </div>

                <!--SECTION DIVIDER IMAGE-->
                <div class="breakImageDiv" style="width: 100%">
                    <img src="../images/EchoPet_Line_Break_PNG.png" alt="Divider" style="width:100%" height="39"/>
                </div>

            </div>

            </div>

        <div style="float:left; width:100%">
            <div id="annouceDiv" style="width:100%">

                <div class="sectionHeader" style="margin-right:60px">
                    &nbsp&nbsp Plano
                </div>
                <br/>

                <div class="announceSection" style="text-align:center; margin-right:60px">

                        <iframe 
                            src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3375.2154892306807!2d-110.97141080000001!3d32.22536379999999!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x86d6711e54972b5f%3A0x655603b7f78ec698!2s240+N+Stone+Ave%2C+Tucson%2C+AZ+85701!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1422889378316"
                            width="95%" height="450" postion="relative" bottom="460px" frameborder="0" style="border:0">
                        </iframe>

                </div>

                <!--SECTION DIVIDER IMAGE-->
                <div class="breakImageDiv" style="width:100%">
                    <img src="../images/EchoPet_Line_Break_PNG.png" class="breakImagePic" alt="Divider" style="width:100%"/>
                </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

            <!--FOOTER-->
            <div id="footer" style="position:relative; bottom:0">
            </div>

         <!--Javascript for header, nav, and footer-->                          
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/NewWebTest/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/NewWebTest/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
            $("#header").load("/NewWebTest/header.html");
            $("#navigation").load("/NewWebTest/navigation.html");
            $("#footer").load("/NewWebTest/footer.html");
            });
        </script>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

A lot of the other CSS styles in the middle are lined up and fine, didn't feel the need to add those, unless it is requested.  I've looked everywhere on here and other articles for the past day, and can't quite find what I'm looking for.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `<div id="footer">` add a style with `clear:both;` reason it's sitting on top of your iframe is because you have your `iframe` `float:left`. You need to clear your floats.

Comment: That got the footer down! But it's still sitting on top. Almost like the body of the page doesn't know there's a footer there.  See it here: http://www.jp.pima.gov/NewWebTest/Info/GeneralInfo-Spanish.html  It's so close!

Comment: May I ask why you have your `.footer1` class absolutely positioned? Simply remove that absolute positioning as well as the `bottom` and the `left` from the `.footer1` class and it'll fix it. What positioning does is it takes it out of the normal document flow of the DOM (document object model). https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Holy yes! Thank you so much! That was it! I get it takes it out, I still don't understand all of the positionings and everything.  I hope after this project is done, I'll be able to sit down and learn more.  Thank you again.